# Graphically Representing Digital Signals With GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the minimal example:

```
signals <- tibble(
  time = 1:20,
  long = c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10)),
  medium = c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5),rep(0,5),rep(1,5)),
  short = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(0,2),rep(1,2)),
  random = c(sample(2,20,TRUE)-1)
)

signals %<>% 
  pivot_longer(!time,names_to = "signals")
```

I'd like to use ggplot to display a variety of signals which are either 1 or 0.  I've looked into dot plot and bar plot, but I somehow keep turning them into histograms, which I do not want.  How would I create a plot which looks generally like this, but without being a histogram:

[image]

Comment: It's a strange graphic you want here, but if it is what you're looking for, is it possible to add to the question the code that made it possible to obtain the graphic you're showing as an example? I imagine that you get with the `plot` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pivot your data into long format, then simply plot time on the x axis and the `name` column of your pivoted data frame on the y axis. The `fill` would be the `value` column:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(signals, -time), 
       aes(time, name, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_point(size = 8, shape = 21) + 
  scale_y_discrete('Signals') +
  scale_fill_manual('Value', values = c('white', 'black')) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

However, a more typical way to create a binary signal plot would be to use `geom_step`:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(signals, -time), aes(time, value)) +
  geom_step(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous('Signals', expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous('Time (s)', limits = c(0, 20)) +
  facet_grid(name~., switch = 'y') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(size = 14, angle = 0, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works wonderfully.  Unfortunately, with how many signals I actually have, and the length of time observed, a step plot becomes a bit more difficult to understand further down.  I was thinking that adding some colour would make it faster to understand, but it looks like I'll be going back to the steps.